# Dereferencing pointer and storing reference to the pointed data, then getting address of reference and performing pointer arithmetic on it. c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, undefined-behavior

In order to make a diagram(of my own, to understand pointers/pointers-to-pointers/arrays) that is out of the scope this question, I want to know if it is adequate to assume the following:

```
int *intptr = new int[10]{0};
int &intref = *intptr;
int thirdInt = *((&intref)+2);//is this defined behavior and always equivalent to intptr[2]?????
delete [] intptr;
```

as the only comment in the code asks: does this code invoke undefined behavior or not work as expected by the comment?

Comment: Taking the address of a reference yields the address of the original object; a reference is simply another name for an object, after all, an alias. So yes, you can use it like any other pointer to that object. (Whether people *expect* that is another question, for example if the reference is a function argument.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then getting address of reference

To clarify this bit: It is not possible to "get address of a reference". When you apply addressof operator on a reference, you are getting the address of the referred object.

> this code invoke undefined behavior

No.

> always equivalent to intptr[2]?????

Yes (except in case of a class type with strange overload for operator &, but those are and should be hardly ever used).

Comment: In what cases would a compiler be required to allow for the possibility that code could make use of a reference to access something other than the object being referred to?  Given e.g. `void doSomething(int &arg); int test() { struct { int x,y; } foo; foo.y = 2; doSomething(foo.x); return foo.y; }` would a compiler that knows nothing about `doSomething()` beyond its prototype be required to allow for the possibility that `doSomething(foo.x)` could alter `foo.y`?

Comment: @supercat For standard layout classes such as the shown, the compiler does need to allow for such possibility. For non-standard layout classes, it probably technically doesn't need to, but there may be other reasons why proving that optimisation based on such detail is OK may be too difficult in general to be of practical use. For array elements such as in the question, compiler definitely cannot assume that reference to one element isn't used to access siblings.

Comment: Having a means of indicating "this reference will only be used to access the indicated object, and not to derive references to enclosing objects" would facilitate spme useful optimizations, and I can't offhand think of any situations where code which wanted to be able to access an enclosing objects would accept a reference rather than a pointer.  Passing a *pointer* to an array element for purposes of accessing the whole array is idiomatic in C and C++, but is passing a *reference* for such purpose likewise idiomatic?

Comment: @supercat Idiomatic, no. But also not something disallowed by the rules. "This reference will only be used to access the indicated object" isn't by itself sufficient to allow optimisation I think. There has to also be a guarantee that the function doesn't know the address of the enclosing object through other means such as global state or perhaps a reference or pointer within the inner object. In the extremely simple example in your first comment, such proof might just be possible if we were able to express the scope of the access from the reference. But in general the the proof is complex.

Comment: A compiler must generally allow for the possibility that an opaque function may modify any part of any global object, any object to which a function has received a pointer from outside code, or any static or automatic object whose address has been exposed to outside code.  A compiler that attempted to identify all objects to which any of those conditions could apply, however, could easily identify many objects to which none of them could possibly apply.